# Remove form loader or spinner in shipping address one page checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, validation, guest-checkout

How do I remove the page loader or spinner when user entered value in the field i.e Phone Number field? I believe this is the default design by Magento to check on the validation part or making ajax requests but is there any specific reason why such page loader or spinner appeared when any keyup entered in the Phone Number field?

[image: Example behaviour]

Comment: This is default checkout or adds any module for that??

Comment: @BhavinGohil it is default magento loader, tested it using Luma theme it still have that kind of loader

Comment: Hi, anyone here how to solve this ?